# Access UIToolbar from a UIBarButton

Tags: ios, facebook-ios-sdk

I have a UIBarButton, and I'd like to access the UIToolbar which holds it. Since the button isn't a UIView I can't simply get the superview. Does anyone know if a way to do this?

Tim

P.S. If you're curious as to why I need this, I'm using the FBFriendPicker class from the Facebook SDK, and this presents the friends list with a UIToolbar at the top. I need to change the tint of the toolbar, but the SDK only gives me access to the button. I could change the source of course, but I'd rather not have the maintenance overhead of my own changes on the SDK.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, it doesn't seem possible to find the UIToolbar from a UIButtonItem.

To solve the issue at hand I instead found it from the controller....

```
    [self.friendPickerController presentModallyFromViewController:_controller
                                                         animated:YES
                                                          handler:nil];

    // Find the UIToolbar so that we can change its colour

    for (UIView *view in self.friendPickerController.view.subviews) {
        if ([view isKindOfClass:[UIToolbar class]]) {
            UIToolbar *toolbar = (UIToolbar *)view;
            toolbar.tintColor = BRANDINGTEXTCOLOUR;
            break;
        }
    }
```